# Word Count in MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to create a co-occurrence count collection for a processed plain text Wikipedia dump.  I'm using the Java API for MongoDB and my document structure is fairly simple:

{ w: word1#word2, c: count }

I have an index on "w" and am updating the counts for every pair I encounter using the query:

```
coll2.update(new BasicDBObject("w",word), new BasicDBObject("$inc",new BasicDBObject("c",1)),true,false);
```

Are there are any other optimizations I could do to speed up my word count process?  I'm currently at ~27 million word pairs and from the "mongod" terminal I'm seeing an unending stream of queries taking anywhere from 100-1000ms (which I think is "slow").  Through my Google'ing, a MapReduce approach seems like the usual way to tackle large word count problems.  But I do not know much about MapReduce and from my basic understanding I'd need more than one machine (which I don't have).

Thanks,
Anthony

Answer (score 0):

In theory your approach is fine, as long as you do exact match of the "w" field.
If you use a regexp or other, the index may not be used efficiently.
You can run the equivalent find with explain() to check on the index behavior.

Also make sure that the whole index on "w" can fit in RAM, as well as most documents.
If mongo needs to read from disk to update the documents, it will become very slow depending on your disks.

Potential workaround:

- do some of the counting on the client side (using a hashmap) then insert at the end of each document processing.
- you can try map reduce. You will gain in that it is executed within the db. But it requires executing javascript which will probably be slower in the end. Coming up is the aggregation framework and MR improvements in mongo 2.2. They are both easy to use when you try out.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I believe I am doing exact match on my "w" field as I construct the word pair the same way every time (word1#word2 where word1 lexicographically precedes word2).  And I like the idea of storing counts in a map first and then inserting!  That should cut down on the numbers of queries.

Comment: Also, how can I check if my whole index on "w' fits in RAM?

Comment: You can see each index size from db.collection.stats()

Comment: If you are seeing a lot of disk IO then most likely you are page faulting because things dont fit in ram, and things will get real slow as with any db.